# Getting fine detail in colliders?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D physics game that involves collisions between objects which at the moment use complex polygon colliders.

When the objects collide, I get the normal of the contact point using otherObject.contacts[0].normal, and knock the objects apart in equal-but-opposite directions using Rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition, with the force being the normal multiplied by a constant.

Most of the time this works flawlessly, but I've found that when the collision occurs with a concave section (aka: an inward "dip") in the polygon collider, the normal will be flipped, and the objects will instead get pushed towards each other.

Alternatively, are there any other ways I could go about solving this?

[image]

The blue circled area is an example of a problematic concave section

Comment: Just as a curiosity ... *"knock the objects apart ... using Rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition"*  Why would you do this? The PhysX will entirely do this for you automatically, right??

Comment: I understand the confusion. To clarify: When the objects collide, they're supposed to get blown backwards (imagine an explosion at the point of contact)

Comment: Hmm, PhysX will do that for you, just change the PhysicMaterial right?

Comment: True, but I want the knockback force to be consistent, and not dependent on the collision speed.

Comment: fair, then (A) I have no clue why what you're doing isn't working .. you're quite sure that maybe ***it is working*** but it's actually bouncing off a different part than you think, or some such and (B) indeed you could easily do it using "small colliders" - or rather, if you MUST use a poly collider, then custom-make it so it is, you know, "less detailed" (but still as detailed as you need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, are there any other ways I could go about solving this?

Yes, the standard thing in vid games is that most stuff has **many small simple colliders**, rather than one large complex collider.

## This is a basic of game engineering.

(It can be very surprising to hobbyists and folks new to the field.)

So, imagine a car in any ordinary 3D game. You'd have a collider for the rear bumper, one for the front, maybe one for "left doors" and so on.  Very typically, each has to react in a different way, and you need to know which area was touched.

In your case if the 2D poly has say 12 edges, just make 12 "small" as it were colliders for each of the edges.

We know nothing about your setup since no screenshot, but that could possibly work.

Note however that Unity's 2D poly collider in fact *already does know to slice the object in to smaller triangle-like shapes* if it is concave - I'm surprused it dinnae work for you.

---

Further: now that we can see your image.

In any video game on Earth, the way you'd do that helmet is with a square collider as in orange:

[image]

If (for some reason .. why? for what purpose? how? where? what possible reason could there be?) you were making *the most precise video game, ever created by humans, on an entirely new plane of engineering, for some imaginary new hardware with quantum warpspace cores*,  ... in that case ... you'd maybe add the two extra colliders to cover the horns. But nobody would ever notice the difference.

I appreciate you may be doing something exceptionally unusual, like a "close up game" ("you're an atom in medieval Scandinavia, bouncing off helmets" or whatever), in which case there'd be some other solution.

The very short answer is you've stumbled on one of the most surprising things about game technology ... *we use crappy, simple, colliders, you've been tricked all your life in every title you play!*

Comment: Would using multiple smaller colliders affect performance? Also, I've added a screenshot of a sample object to the question.

Comment: Hehe :) The assembled characters are pretty small (~1/40th of screen space at maximum camera zoom-in), so I suppose pixel-perfect collision was pretty overkill. I'll go ahead and switch to box colliders.
This is my first physics-based game, so I'm just learning as I go along.
Anyway, thank you so much for the help and advice :)

Comment: YOU'VE GOT IT !  enjoy.  yup, that's exactly how games are made. the "car" example is a good one.  cheers