# How to animate SCNNode.scale using SCNTransaction

Tags: swift, scenekit, scntranscaction

```swift
let balloon: SCNNode

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 4
SCNTransaction.animationTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
balloon.scale.x = 2.28
balloon.scale.y = 2.28
balloon.scale.z = 2.28
// or balloon.scale = SCNVector3(2.28, 2.28, 2.28)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

The above does not animate. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408050-scale) say `.scale` is animatable however the new scale is applied immediately.

I have the same issue with the material's diffuse color.

The following works:

```swift
balloon.runAction(SCNAction.scale(to: 2.28, duration: 4), forKey: "scale")
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [self] in
    balloon.removeAction(forKey: "scale")
}
```

however sometimes I prefer `SCNTransaction` because an animation can be replaced or stopped just by setting a new value (directly or via another animation) instead of having to explicitly stop it like with `.removeAnimation`, and also because of its main function which is atomicity.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your ballon node have a physics body?

Comment: @zay Removing the physics body did the trick, both scaling and diffuse can now animate via SCNTransaction as expected. This is very weird as the physics body doesn't scale anyway so it shouldn't get in the way. It shouldn't get in the way of anything else either. Please post an answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the physics body of your node that prevents the SCNTransaction to run as expected. This is, as I remeber, by design. Physics bodies cannot be scaled. It could be an option to temporary remove the physics body and re-apply it after the SCNTransaction has completed.

Comment: The physics geometry is kept separate from the SCNNode geometry so there's no obvious reason which prevents animating colors or the scaling of the visible model.

Comment: @oxygen I don't know your exact rig, but the fact that a node HAS a physics body (usually) means that that body, is, in short, manipulated by the physics engine every single frame.  It's totally normal it would seemingly "prevent" the object from making other changes.  Also, experiment with changing the `.type` of the physics body .. dynamic, kinematic etc

Comment: @Fattie I am reading what you’re saying as: the physics engine excludes other manipulators which makes sense. Thanks! I only needed physics bodies to precompute scaling animations with precision using collisions of dense models (very slow), so I just removed the body for when the app actually runs for the user.

Comment: cheers @oxygen again, another approach might be as simple as toggling the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbodytype

Comment: @Fattie Because I had to use the concavePolyhedron shape type (it is all about precision) so I’m forced to use static body type to still register the collisions I need.  It is also painfully slow as I had to reinstantiate the physics body geometry after each scale attempt to find the boundaries I need. All in all an excercise in futility which will never recoup the time I put into it (I could have just went with scaling by hand and ball park it using my own two eyes to get the values which will have to be hard coded).

Comment: ah, just a very general comment: the physics engine used in iOS is incredibly imprecise  :)  :) :) :)  It is very much a game physics engine (just like PhysX in Unity, and the same with all game physics engines).  A continuous, fluid dynamics physics engine (like "Bullet Real-Time Physics Simulation" ie used to make movies etc in non real time) may be more what you need.  But, almost certainly, not fully understand your project, I would just program it by hand.  PS memorizing this famous book is a right ofd passage for physics programmers  :)  ..

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Third/dp/1435458869

Comment: BTW (I realize u're not programming a game but) you never, ever, ever use mesh colliders in actual game development!  this is an incredibly common misconception.  typical rant by someone about this, trying to help unity newbs  :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184283/294884

Comment: no problemo!!  rock on